# how to promote widget to different classes with different selection?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt5

I am using pyqt5 to plot stock trend on a widget. Sometime the widget only has one plot, sometimes I'd like to have 3 subplots. I designed two classes for same widget like below. Firstly I promote the widget to the below first class with only one plot. Later when I select different button to plot different plots, I'd like to change the plot to have 3 subplots, which means I need to change class for the widget.  Is it possible to change class for same widget with different selections? or Is there any alternative way?

```
class gui_stock_oneplot(QWidget):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self,parent)
        self.canvas=FigureCanvas(Figure())
        
        vertical_layout=QVBoxLayout()
        vertical_layout.addWidget(self.canvas)
        
        self.canvas.axis1=self.canvas.figure.add_subplot(111)
        self.canvas.axis2=self.canvas.axis1.twinx()
        self.canvas.axis3=self.canvas.axis1.twinx()
        self.canvas.figure.set_facecolor("white")  #lightblue
        self.setLayout(vertical_layout)
```

want to change widget class to:

```
class gui_stock_3plot(QWidget):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self,parent)
        self.canvas=FigureCanvas(Figure())
        
        vertical_layout=QVBoxLayout()
        vertical_layout.addWidget(self.canvas)
        
        self.canvas.axis1=self.canvas.figure.add_subplot(311)
        self.canvas.axis2=self.canvas.figure.add_subplot(312)
        self.canvas.axis3=self.canvas.figure.add_subplot(313)
        self.canvas.figure.set_facecolor("white")  #lightblue
        self.setLayout(vertical_layout)
```

Comment: Your question is unclear, explain yourself better. Please provide a [mre]

Comment: sorry eyllanesc. yes my question is unclear. I am not sure how to ask? I am new to Pyqt5. Basically, I designed one widget to plot area. I'd like to let same widget  having flexibility to plot one subplot and 3 subplots. How to do it?  The way I am thinking is to change widget class. Thanks

Comment: Maybe if you provide the MRE then you could help, otherwise I will go my way

Comment: With "promote" do refer to using custom class through promoted widget in Designer? If that's so, no, you can't: once the ui is instantiated, the widget instance are created, you cannot "change class" of an instance (this has nothing to do with PyQt, it's a basic concept behind classes and instances on any language). If you create a table, you can customize it (subclass table) with 3, 4 or more legs, a width and height, but once you create it you cannot change it *into* a helicopter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "promote" the OP means using a custom widget in .ui then the answer is no, you can't.

Clearly the OP has an XY problem since he is wondering about a possible solution: how to switch between 2 classes a widget that was promoted, instead of the background problem: How to change the plots in a custom widget?

For the underlying problem there are at least 2 possible solutions:

1. You can implement all the logic in the same widget first by cleaning the figure and then repainting:

   ```py
   class Widget(QWidget):
       def __init__(self):
           super().__init__()
           layout = QVBoxLayout(self)

           self.canvas = FigureCanvas(Figure())
           layout.addWidget(self.canvas)

       def one_plot(self):
           self.canvas.figure.clear()

           self.canvas.axis1 = self.canvas.figure.add_subplot(111)
           self.canvas.axis2 = self.canvas.axis1.twinx()
           self.canvas.axis3 = self.canvas.axis1.twinx()
           self.canvas.figure.set_facecolor("white")  # lightblue

           self.canvas.draw()

       def three_plot(self):
           self.canvas.figure.clear()

           self.canvas.axis1 = self.canvas.figure.add_subplot(311)
           self.canvas.axis2 = self.canvas.figure.add_subplot(312)
           self.canvas.axis3 = self.canvas.figure.add_subplot(313)
           self.canvas.figure.set_facecolor("white")  # lightblue

           self.canvas.draw()
   ```

   Then just use the clicked signal of each function to change plots:

   ```
   self.one_button.clicked.connect(self.foo_widget.one_plot)
   self.three_button.clicked.connect(self.foo_widget.three_plot)
   ```
2. The other solution is not to promote but to use a QStackedWidget. The logic is to add each widget to the QStackedWidget and change the index with the buttons.

   ```py
   self.one_widget = gui_stock_oneplot()
   one_index = self.stacked_widget.addWidget(self.one_widget)
   self.one_button.clicked.connect(
       lambda *args, index=one_index: self.stacked_widget.setCurrentIndex(index)
   )

   self.three_widget = gui_stock_3plot()
   three_index = self.stacked_widget.addWidget(self.three_widget)
   self.three_button.clicked.connect(
       lambda *args, index=three_index: self.stacked_widget.setCurrentIndex(index)
   )
   ```

Comment: wow, eyllanesc, that is very impressive! you made my night.  The first solution is easier for me to understand.  2nd approach I never did it before, but it is very smart. That is really awesome! Thank you so much eyllanesc, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Another solution I am thinking is not to define any subplot in the class to be promoted. Instead, could I just add subplots in main program. For example,             self.widgetPlot.canvas.axis1=self.widgetPlot.canvas.figure.add_subplot(311)
            self.widgetPlot.canvas.axis2=self.widgetPlot.canvas.figure.add_subplot(312)